# Is it possible to access insights data on a particular Open Graph story via one of the Facebook APIs?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-insights

Given an Open Graph story ID, is it possible to read insights Impression and Referral data on the story via any of the Facebook APIs?

A thorough review of the API documentation suggests it's not (but FB's API docs can get out of date) and previous SO questions have not been promising (but none of the answers seem definitive and anyway times change). Something like the following seems like a reasonable guess for where they might be available:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[og_story_id]/insights
```

Testing queries along those lines does not error, but also hasn't turned up any real data.

As a addendum and potential hack, is it possible to access the comment or like count for an Open Graph story?

Comment: Aren't the comments and likes available at /[OG STORY ID] ?

Comment: Igy - yes you're right, on testing it's possible to access the likes and comments of an Open Graph story using the original poster's access_token. Insights still don't appear to be an option though.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to update the existing isight using the endpoint the only it allow only the get request post and put is not allowed for this end point